# Update Microsoft Band Me Tile from desktop UWP app

Tags: uwp, microsoft-band, windows-10-universal

As the title states, is it possible to send Me Tile updates from a desktop/tablet app to the band? Or only from the Mobile device it is synced with?

I'm submitting my band-background app to the store and I'm debating if I should make it mobile-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Band can be Bluetooth paired to and used by (Windows Store) applications via the Band SDK on both mobile devices and desktop machines, so there's probably no reason *not* to allow it.  That said, the Band can effectively be paired to only a single device or machine at a time.  I imagine most users will have their Band paired to their phone in order to use the Microsoft Health application (rather than using the desktop sync application), so I wouldn't expect much use on desktop.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying